# Is female squirting involuntary urination?

Tags: physiology, sexuality

During sex some women have a phenomenon called squirting that happens, when they release a large amount of fluid during sex. Recently I have been seeing people stating that squirting is involuntary urination, and others arguing that is not the case, and that it is simple female ejaculation.

Comment: Should probably be migrated to [biology.se].

Comment: @iamnotmaynard i will probably ask there as well, however squirting in general is viewed as almost an urban legend by some.so i figured it would fit well here also.

Comment: I think the linked  Cosmo article pretty much answers the question despite the personal anecdotes later in article: "When the contents of this fluid have been analyzed, it's actually — yes — closer to pee than it is to female ejaculate."

Comment: If you're asking whether it happens or whether it's urban legend, this is the right place.  If you're asking why it happens, what it consists of, or similar, then Biology is better.

Comment: What is the counterclaim (If it is not Urine)?

Comment: @Jamiec many people claim that its simply female ejaculation, just in larger quantities then normal, based they say, because it does not smell like urine. ill see if i can find an article with the counterclaim most of the counterclaim comes from individuals. (which sparked this question)

Comment: If the vulgar word squirting could be replaced with female ejaculation then I think it would invite more serious answers.

Comment: @NeilMeyer actually, female ejaculation is not the same as female squirting. So editing that word would change the entire meaning of this question. AFAIK squirting is the accepted word for this action. Female ejaculation is the release of just a small amount of liquid, squirting is the release of large amounts they are not the same, and actually your confusion on the wording is part of the controversy im asking about here.

Comment: Linked article does not make the claim.

Comment: @nomenagentis - fixed by removal? That's hardly fixed....

Comment: @nomenagentis I suppose, but it doesnt get this question any closer to getting reopened.

Comment: @Sklivvz added the counter claim at the end, also i have some screen shots of an argument on this topic from Reddit, whether they would help or not.

Comment: There is still no evidence of notability

Comment: @nomenagentis the problem im having finding a notable "claim" is i only have comments in forum threads, since most news articles of the past year seem to agree its urine now, while this agreement either hasnt spread out, or there is lots of fighting in regards to whether or not they actually believe these studies.